# Trying to automate voucher code input with Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Ok so, I'm 16 and am new to Python. I need projects to do to help me learn, so I came up with a PlayStation Plus code generator as a project and so far it does:

-Generates a code
-Logs in to Account Management at Sony's site
-Enters code at redeem section
-Checks if error occurred

```
voucher_box = driver.find_element_by_id("voucherCode")
redeem_button = driver.find_element_by_id("redeemGiftCardButton")
while i < amount:
    voucher_box.clear()
    currentcode = codegen.codegen()
    voucher_box.send_keys(currentcode)
    redeem_button.click()
    if "The Prepaid Card code you entered is incorrect or is no longer valid" in driver.page_source:
        print("Error found")
    else:
        print("Error not found")
    i += 1
```

It works completely fine if only done ONCE but if for example, I set amount to 2, I get my error message "Error found" and then it crashes and gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/M4SS3CR3/PycharmProjects/UKP/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    voucher_box.clear()
  File "C:\Users\M4SS3CR3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 87, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\M4SS3CR3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 461, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\M4SS3CR3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\M4SS3CR3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9454)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///C:/Users/M4SS3CR3/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpn3rxlnty/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9039)
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///C:/Users/M4SS3CR3/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpn3rxlnty/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10090)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///C:/Users/M4SS3CR3/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpn3rxlnty/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/Users/M4SS3CR3/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpn3rxlnty/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/M4SS3CR3/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpn3rxlnty/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/M4SS3CR3/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpn3rxlnty/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated, I apologize before hand if this is not detailed enough.

Comment: Selenium is tricky... That being said, it seems like it's crashing because the element is not found on the page.. You might want to add a time.sleep(3) after the button click to give the page enough time to reload the elements... Also make sure that the page does in fact contain the ID voucherCode after you've made one submission.  An easy why to test for this is with chrome tools and doing the process manually to check for changes in the pages html

Comment: @reticentroot I've tried both of the things you've said. time.sleep() does not help, same error again. I also checked for the element after submission and it is still there, same ID and everything.

Comment: how about right after you i+=1  you force selenium to reload the page the page (driver.get()) and move your voucher_box variable and redeem_button variable inside the while loop.  So that the elements can be found each time.  Ultimately you can wrap everything in the while loop inside a try except block and on the exception pass or sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idea of what I mentioned in the comment

```
while i < amount:
    try:
      counter = 0
      # make sure that the elements can be found
      # try ten times and then break out of loop
      while counter < 10:
        try:
          voucher_box = driver.find_element_by_id("voucherCode")
          redeem_button = driver.find_element_by_id("redeemGiftCardButton")
          break
        except:
          time.sleep(1)
          counter += 1

      voucher_box.clear()
      currentcode = codegen.codegen()
      voucher_box.send_keys(currentcode)
      redeem_button.click()
      if "The Prepaid Card code you entered is incorrect or is no longer valid" in driver.page_source:
          print("Error found")
      else:
          print("Error not found")
      i += 1
      driver.get("my page") # may not need this line because the elements were moved inside the while loop
      time.sleep(3) # give the page enough time to load
    except:
      pass
```

You can also go as far as to do something like html.find(ID) > -1: do something else the ID wasn't present on the page so quit or reload. Also more then anything else it's probably better to move

```
voucher_box = driver.find_element_by_id("voucherCode")
          redeem_button = driver.find_element_by_id("redeemGiftCardButton")
```

inside the while loop because so that the object is the correct object through everyloop.  What could be happening is that you're using elements that belonged to a different dom.